# MPMoviePlayerViewController doesn't show well when playing video

Tags: objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I trying to show video on my App. The App hides the iPhone top panel. The player seems to work fine. There is just one annoying problem: when the player shows the video, it sometimes show the top panel and sometime hides it. When it is hidden, the video player panel is pushed a little (the same size of the panel that used to be there). Is is Apple bug? Am I doing something wrong?
Here is my code:

```
- (void) showFullscreenMediaWithURL: (NSURL *) mediaURL
{
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *ctrl = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: mediaURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(playbackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:ctrl.moviePlayer];
    ctrl.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    ctrl.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [ctrl setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:ctrl];  
    [ctrl release];
}

-(void) playbackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
   NSLog(@"Finished playback");  
   MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:player];
   [player stop];
   [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
   [[captureManager session] startRunning];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

if by iPhone top panel you mean the iPhone Status bar, then the solution should be simple.
Just before present/dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated add the following:

```
// Hide Status Bar        
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
// Show Status Bar
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

**Update**: I can see what seems to be your problem.

First, the upper bar with the network indication icons and other information is the [status bar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html) (and nothing else). Your problem seems to be more ViewController related then a MediaPlayer. In other words, If you would have try to "push" some other ViewController to full screen (as the player is) you would have experience the exact same issue.

Second, the proper way, or I might say: my preferred way, of loading a view controller to full screen is the following:

1. Setup a full screen rootViewController which will be loaded on applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions on your appDelegate.
2. On the rootViewController init put your default viewController (the one you used to load from appDelegate). Make sure that the rootViewController.view's frame is filling the screen.
3. Create 2 messages on rootViewController: LoadFullscreen:viewController and dismissFullscreen using present/dismissModelViewController. the setStatusBarHidden messages should be called from here.
4. To Lunch the player on full screen, create the player viewController and perform [rootViewController LoadFullscreen:player];

There are some other ways, but generally, this is the best practice and the method I recommend. It's relatively "a lot of code" to implement, thats why I couldn't help you with code snippers, but the general idea is relatively simple.

I hope that's help, E.G :)

Comment: I tried that already. It doesn't work. My entire App doesn't show status bar (it is hidden when the App starts). When the video is being shown, I see the panel pushed down with no status bar. When I click on the screen one, the status bar is shown.

Comment: Sorry, still can't figure out what you mean. An onscreen video of the iPhone Simulator would be lovely... you can use built-in quicktime for that

Comment: Can I post image attachment here? anyway, it is very simple: when seeing the video, you can still see the iPhone Top Panel. Sometimes is it simply there, and sometimes it is not there, but the space that meant to be for the panel is there. I cannot really hide the top panel: either there is a top panel nor there is a space for the panel. By the way on the space for the panel, you can see the video as well.